# Can I use 2 android phones as walkie talkie? (without internet!)

Tags: wi-fi, 2.2-froyo, data-connection

I want to use 2 (or more) android phones as walkie-talkie (i.e. they talk each other without needing internet/voice call).

Of course this should work with WiFi, because it doesn't make much sense a to have Bluetooth or USB connection for this application.

Comment: Wi-fi implies internet.  What do you mean "without internet"?

Comment: It does not. If I establish an ad-hoc connection between two android phones, I'm using wifi but not internet.

Comment: Kind of tangental: wouldn't you then be close enough to just talk to each other? I guess you might be separated by a wall or something, but the range of an ad-hoc network probably isn't going to be too large...

Comment: An entire town may be under the same wifi (there may be repetitors, lan/wan bridging an so on...)

Comment: @michel: but if you're under the same wifi, then you're not using an ad-hoc connection between the two phones, but rather relying on a third party.  Besides, as far as the phone is concerned, there's no difference between ad-hoc and other wifi.  Either way you're using TCP/IP over wifi.  The only difference is that your connectivity suffers.

Comment: Why not Bluetooth?

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, but again: wifi!=internet and wifi range may cover large areas, therefore my question is interesting.

Comment: @Dan: Bluetooth is too short ranged, and bluetooth tethering requirest at least a rooted phone (plus a bluetooth access point... a bit too much complicated for my tastes)

Comment: @michele If you want to talk via ad-hoc, then you're close enough to drop the phone and just talk.  If you want to talk over a large WiFi network, you'll also have internet through that network, no?

Comment: @Mattew The real problem is talking WITHOUT cordless/landline and WITHOUT internet. What if someone is confined within one room and need to talk outside? What if internet is down/unavailable/expensive? What if I OWN my wifi and don't want to relay on internet? What if I don't want my voice data to go over untrusted network?... I hope my point is clear.

Comment: I found [WiFi Walkie Talkie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jsl.wfwt) useful. Very small and simple, open-source, requires no permissions except reading the mic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what I use that do not need an internet connection:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidintercom

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remaller.android.wifitalkie_lite

Answer (score 21):

The project mentioned by BobFlemming is the [Serval project](http://www.servalproject.org/), and they are also on [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/ServalProject). The android application will be available soon apparently.

Thought I'd mention because not entirely straightforward to find it through the youtube link and that the twitter account isn't advertised on the site. Also I cannot +1 or comment yet so adding it as a reply.

Answer (score 11):

Its been tested by a group here:

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2011/01/researchers-enable-mesh-wifi-networking-for-android-smartphones.ars

So it is possible.

Answer (score 8):

The previously mentioned serval project now has an android app available - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.servalproject

Comment: And here's another app like that - Walkie-Talki by Wi-Fi and BlueTooth - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidintercom

Comment: i wonder if someone has the tutorial how to make the simple mash-wifi app just like they created that app..... @Varrah

Answer (score 5):

here is a project on sourceforge , please refer whether it help your need or not..
just link here,

> http://android-ptt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Seems to have died before it really took off.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using the [WiFi Walkie Talkie app](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.jsl.wfwt/). It doesn't have much in the way of flash, but it works extremely simply.

As a bonus, it is open-source and ad-free.

Comment: "or create a mobile access point on one device and connect all other devices to this access point."

Answer (score 0):

[Wifi Walkie Talkies](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.walkietalkie.scully) is a free app I found. I use it round the house and garden to talk to the wife and kids.

It doesn't use any of your data, call or text allowance, it just works on your home/office wifi. No need to configure anything it just works.. Test on and Android and Backberry Z10.

Comment: Does this work without an internet connection? Your answer (and the app description) doesn't specify if it works with ad-hoc connections or if it requires full internet access.

Comment: I thought you were referencing the [Wifi Walkie Talkie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jsl.wfwt) app, and upvoted for that app, which just works. But, this post promotes a different app.

Answer (score -2):

There are many push to talk apps on the Marketplace, but they all required an Internet connection. As far as I know, Android doesn't support ad-hoc WiFi connections.

Comment: Android doesn't support ad-hoc WiFi connections without rooting (the only thing that prevents it is explicit check in the system library, so rooted phones and custom ROMs like CyanogenMod support it), but you can build an ad-hoc network from managed connections too and Android supports becoming AP.