# How can I establish an AD-HOC Wi-Fi connection on my tablet?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks

I'm not an expert in this kind of subject. I'm reading that I need to root my tablet.

What does root mean? *All the instructions are really difficult.*

How can I make this AD-HOC Wi-Fi connection in my Sony S tablet?

<sup>I'm running Android 4.0</sup>

Comment: Could you add some information on the other device involved? Especially, what OS is it running?

Comment: To answer your first question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean For your implied second question, see: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device

Comment: There is also this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections

Answer (score 5):

There are two other Q&As here which might help you (in fact, there are several more, but most of them -- as you wrote -- are a bit "techy" or, as you put it, "really difficult"):

- [Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections) could be used ith the second device involved is running Windows, and seems not to involve rooting your device
- [Connect android phones through adhoc wifi network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/connect-android-phones-through-adhoc-wifi-network) is just "slightly techy", but requires root, and the Android SDK on a computer

If rooting your device is no problem for you, the second approach should be possible also without the SDK -- if you have a terminal emulator such as [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) installed on your Android device. You could then execute the commands quoted there within the terminal emulator, but probably need to prefix them with the `su` command (to have them run by root):

```
su ifconfig wlan0 up
su iwconfig mode auto;iwconfig wlan0 essid "your SSID" channel 11 mode auto
su ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.x netmask 255.255.255.0
```

As explained,

> *your SSID* should be replaced with the name of your Adhoc network, and *10.0.0.x* is a different IP you give each device.

I didn't test/verify that, but from my Linux knowledge, it sounds quite reasonable. Drawback is, you would need to execute those commands each time you need to establish the ad-hoc connection -- but here some other app could kick in, once you verified the steps are working. One I found is [Script Manager - SManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager) -- but there were some easier ones I just cannot remember at the moment. If this is an acceptable approach to you, I can update my answer and add a few more tools to compensate.

**EDIT:**

Here's the one I had in mind to make the script-running easier: [Scripter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faziklogic.scripter)