# Why can't my samsung galaxy R connect to my laptop Wi-Fi, but is able to connect to others?

Tags: samsung, connectify

Why can't my samsung galaxy R connect to my laptop Wi-Fi, but is able to connect to others? I'm using connectify program in my laptop and windows xp.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/?sub=b&utm_expid=22708698-14) is limited to ad-hoc networking:

> **Support for Windows 8, 7, XP, and Vista** – XP and Vista Ad-Hoc Mode only

[Android doesn't support ad-hoc networks](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections) without [modification or manual configuration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/how-can-i-establish-an-ad-hoc-wi-fi-connection-on-my-tablet?lq=1) (which will require rooting the device).

Comment: If I remember correctly, Android actually supports ad-hoc since 1.6 (Donut) but by default disabled in kernel. A simple wpa_supplicant tweak is needed to enable it back in my HTC G1 before.

Comment: @forums: Yes, as I said (and linked to) - it's not supported off-the-shelf, but with root it's doable.