# Enabling AdHoc Networking on ICS to Connect to AdHoc Devices

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-networks

I'm looking for a way to connect my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.0.x) to my laptop via adhoc wifi. (The laptop will act as my wireless NAS.)

The [WiFi Ad Hoc enabler for Android](http://www.arenddeboer.com/wifi-ad-hoc-enabler-for-android/) does not work on the Galaxy Nexus. (The statistics at at that link show 0 successes and 13 failures for GNex owners who tried it. However, it works for many other devices.)

I also see [this advice](http://www.galaxynexusforum.com/forum/galaxy-nexus-os/3815-enabling-adhoc-networking-connect-adhoc-devices.html):
You need a modified wpa_supplicant file in /system/bin.

What modifications are needed to the wpa_supplicant file in /system/bin?

I see a couple proposed solutions for other devices, but nothing for the Galaxy Nexus.

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19133/12444
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/4147/12444
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/2973-ad-hoc-network/

However, I see [this response](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12689/12444): "patching the wpa_suplicant isn't generic and frankly I'd call that method useless."

What is the best solution? Can anyone shed more light on the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can tether mobile data of your Galaxy Nexus over Wi-Fi, you have full-featured ad-hoc network. If you are not sure, install [Wireless Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.tether) (root access is required).
After connecting Laptop to this `MobileAP`, look for IPs of client and `Default Gateway` (`ipconfig /all` cmd command works fine with Windows; [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing) can also be used). IP of `Default Gateway` is IP of your Android device. You can use these IPs in any networking service you want. It works.

**Another Approach**
In ad-hoc networking, it doesn't matter which point is broadcasting SSID. So, you can make your laptop virtual router too. Connect your Galaxy Nexus to it & do whatever you want.
To make your laptop virtual router with NAS support, I'd recommend you to install [Connectify Pro](http://www.connectify.me/) (not free). There's a nice free alternative too: [mHotspot](http://mhotspot.com). After connecting your Galaxy Nexus to virtual hotspot created by it, you can use any networking service over it.

Comment: My laptop is running Ubuntu, so neither Connectify or mHotpost will work for me. I don't want to tether the mobile data connection. I want to use my laptop as a wireless NAS (to stream or download files from my laptop to my phone). I don't think you have given me any solution (unless I misunderstand).

Comment: @MountainX You do have the solution. `Wireless Tether` app provides access control to block internet sharing with clients. So, your mobile data usage will not be affected.