# ICS not detecting adhoc network

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-networks

I created an adhoc wireless network on my windows 7 machine. My windows phone is detecting this wireless network but my android ICS phone is not detecting it at all. Why is that?

I have an unrooted phone. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What WiFi channel you are using? Depending on the country you are in, not all channels are "permitted" -- and some Android devices respect that.

Comment: [Enabling AdHoc Networking on ICS to Connect to AdHoc Devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22131/enabling-adhoc-networking-on-ics-to-connect-to-adhoc-devices), [Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections), [How can I establish an AD-HOC Wi-Fi connection on my tablet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/how-can-i-establish-an-ad-hoc-wi-fi-connection-on-my-tablet)