# Video streaming among Android devices using Wi-Fi without Internet

Tags: wi-fi, video-streaming

I am looking for a way to stream online video between 2 or more Android devices over Wifi network created by hotspot tethering.

I found one [that can stream audio online](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/can-i-use-2-android-phones-as-walkie-talkie-without-internet).

Is there something similar but for videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be using a DLNA server app ([This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.dlnaserver.), for example, though there are lots of others) on one device and an appropriate player ([example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dbapp.android.mediahouse)) on the other devices.  Not sure if it would work over a hotspot tether though, but there are free apps available for both ends, so it can't really hurt to try.

EDIT: Oh, misunderstood the question. That's about as easy. There are several apps on the store for running a camera server, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam), for example. You then can use any compatible player to connect and view the camera feed

Comment: It seems the above solution is for file sharing. I am looking for online video (from camera) streaming. In other words, on one end I am recording video and I can see that online on the other end. Is there a solution?