# Can I use android phones and PC as walkie talkie? (without internet!)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, voip

I want to call my PC using my android phone(vice versa) without internet. I think it is possible, but not sure there is a program like that.

PC to Android or Android to PC. Not just Android to Android.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/can-i-use-2-android-phones-as-walkie-talkie-without-internet)

Comment: Without *mobile* internet **or** without any data connection at all?

Comment: Well, I'd say no "internets", but local area of course. There must be any packet data connection available (plain GSM is not an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SIP user agents on both phones and PC.

You can use [SipDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua) or [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple) for Android and a softphone program like [X-Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Lite) on the PC.

Note that you need to set up local accounts when configuring the software. You can then call other parties on the local network directly by their IP:Port.

If you don't want that, you need to install a full blown VoIP proxy like asterisk.

Comment: Do you have any instructions? I tried it but not sure how it works. Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this for over a year, sorry, I don't have any detailed instructions. You need all devices hooked up to the same LAN, and configure local accounts w/o a sip proxy. Then you can call each other by using the IP instead of a normal phone no.